# Solve $\int_D \frac{dz}{z^2+5z+4}$ where $D=\{|z|=1\}$

Tags: integration

I want to solve this closed integral:

$$\int_D \frac{dz}{z^2+5z+4}, \ \ \ \ \text{where }  D=\{|z|=1\}.$$

The roots of

$${z^2+5z+4}$$

Are $z_1=-1 , z_2= -4$, so that means there is a singular point $-1$ on the closed curve $D$. How can I demonstrate by knowing this fact that this integral  diverges?

Comment: Well, as it is the integral isn't even defined. Perhaps you're interested in the Cauchy principal value?

Comment: You know that $\lvert z^2 + 5z + 4\rvert \leqslant C\cdot \lvert z+1\rvert$ on $D$ (you know that you can take $C = 5$), and that estimate shows that the integral doesn't exist as a Lebesgue integral. You can also take a partial fraction decomposition of the integrand, then you only need to care about the $\frac{1}{z+1}$ term, and the calculations are simpler. But note that the principal value of that integral exists, and usually when such integrals occur, one wants the principal value.

Comment: And the principal value of Cauchy is an infinite number? As I know it depends on the singularity type.. what is the singularity type of -1?

Comment: The integrand has a simple pole at $-1$. The principal value of the integral is $\pi i$ times the residue of the integrand at that pole, so $\frac{\pi i}{(-1)+4} = \frac{\pi i}{3}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you